# C - How to show the decimals in a simple arithmetic division?

Tags: c, decimal

There is a very simple thing I cannot accomplish in C.
I just want to make a simple division. The result is rounding the number.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    float a = 5 / 2;

    printf("%0.2f", a);

    return 0;
}
```

The result I'm getting is `2.00` and I want it to be the actual `2.50`.

Comment: The divisor or dividend should be a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

You get the correct result by writing the numbers in your division as floats:

```
float a = 5.0f / 2.0f;
```

Another way would be typecasting:

```
float a = (float)5 / 2;
```

In your code, the numbers are treated as `int`s and only converted to `float` afterward. This gives the wrong rounding.